# Killing a service

Tags: android, android-service, android-background

I was reading about services in Android and especially i came down to this

> While an app is in the foreground, it can create and run both
>   foreground and background services freely. When an app goes into the
>   background, it has a window of several minutes in which it is still
>   allowed to create and use services. At the end of that window, the app
>   is considered to be idle. At this time, the system stops the app's
>   background services, just as if the app had called the services'
>   Service.stopSelf() methods.

In the code below, when the app goes to background after one minute or so the services gets destroy but the thread still executes.

1. So what is the point of killing a service? The process/thread is still being execute.
2. Why killing a service in the first place? What if i want to execute a download process and NOT wanted to be a foreground process?

   ```
   public class HelloService extends Service {
   private Looper mServiceLooper;
   private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;

   // Handler that receives messages from the thread
   private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
       public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
           super(looper);
       }
       @Override
       public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
           // Normally we would do some work here, like download a file.
           // For our sample, we just sleep for 5 seconds.
           Log.d("sssssssss",msg.toString()+"sssssssssss");
           while(true){

               Log.d("sssssssss","sssssssssss");

           }
           // Stop the service using the startId, so that we don't stop
           // the service in the middle of handling another job
           //stopSelf(msg.arg1);
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       // Start up the thread running the service. Note that we create a
       // separate thread because the service normally runs in the process's
       // main thread, which we don't want to block. We also make it
       // background priority so CPU-intensive work doesn't disrupt our UI.
       HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments",
               Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
       thread.start();

       // Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
       mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
       mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
   }

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       // For each start request, send a message to start a job and deliver the
       // start ID so we know which request we're stopping when we finish the job
       Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
       msg.arg1 = startId;
       mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

       // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
       return START_STICKY;
   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
       Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }



   @Nullable
   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       return null;
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: You mentioned a download process. If you're using a service that spawns a thread to perform a download, consider using DownloadManager instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. System is letting You perform a clean finish of the `Service` by triggering its destroy method. Your thread won't run forever, I think 30 min is hard limit before app process is killed.
2. This is new policy since android O to preserve battery life and improve performance. A lot of developers performed heavy operations in background (sockets open non-stop, periodic sensor readings etc.) and without foreground notification users were unaware of why their devices were sluggish and had poor battery uptime.

Read more on [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) doc.

Comment: " I think 30 min is hard limit before app process is killed." Why the app process is killed? An app is killed when in background if the device is low on resources.

Comment: Right, it's the same thing if you spawn a thread from an activity. You better make sure to clean up that thread during the proper lifecycle methods.  Just because you can leave a thread running doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @Nick it still depends on OEM implementation, some (especially chinese) ROMs are much more aggressive when it comes to killing the process than others.